# I cannot figure out why I keep getting syntax error in my Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

```
node('linux') { 
    stage('Create Test Stack') {
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'cfcfed3e-bb3b-4b78-97a1-0ca1e7b9226e', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
            sh 'aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name final-test --template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/rcooper-bucket-bucket/docker-single-server.json --region us-east-1 --parameters ParameterKey=KeyName,ParameterValue=MyKeyPair2 ParameterKey=YourIp,ParameterValue=xxx.xx.xxx.xx/32'
            sh 'aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name stack-test --region us-east-1'
            sh 'aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name stack-test --region us-east-1'       
            sh """
            docker1_ip=\$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name stock-test --region us-east-1 --query \'Stacks[].Outputs[?OutputKey==`manager1PublicIp`].OutputValue[]\' --output text)
            sshagent (credentials: ['c8a72a93-6041-4983-973e-c4f7f3d10ebb']) {
                ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@\${docker1_ip} \'uptime\'
                   }
            """
}
}
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> /workspace/final@tmp/durable-56b16501/script.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. For some reason, that ssh line in the pair of """ won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain value of `docker1_ip` form the shell execute return.Then use `docker1_ip` in sshagent.

```
node('linux') { 
    stage('Create Test Stack') {
        withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'cfcfed3e-bb3b-4b78-97a1-0ca1e7b9226e', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
            sh 'aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name final-test --template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/rcooper-bucket-bucket/docker-single-server.json --region us-east-1 --parameters ParameterKey=KeyName,ParameterValue=MyKeyPair2 ParameterKey=YourIp,ParameterValue=xxx.xx.xxx.xx/32'
            sh 'aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name stack-test --region us-east-1'
            sh 'aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name stack-test --region us-east-1' 

            docker1_ip = sh(
                returnStdout: true,
                script: "aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name stock-test --region us-east-1 --query \'Stacks[].Outputs[?OutputKey==`manager1PublicIp`].OutputValue[]\' --output text"
            ).trim()


            sshagent (credentials: ['c8a72a93-6041-4983-973e-c4f7f3d10ebb']) {
                sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${docker1_ip} uptime"
            }
        }
    }
}
```